# Robot Framework test scripts fail with SSLError

Tags: python, api, automation, openssl, robotframework

I have written Robot Framework test scripts in `.tsv` format to test web-services/APIs. Everything was working fine until today (probably because of the new updates of Robot Framework) when I started to get the following error:

> SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)

This error keeps popping up for the following code in a test script:

```
${headers}=  Create Dictionary Content-Type application/json  Accept application/json
RequestsKeywords.Get Request httpbin ${url} headers=${headers} //ERROR SHOWS FOR THIS STATEMENT
```

I did get a detailed traceback for this error which is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/RequestsLibrary/RequestsKeywords.py", line 298, in get_request
    session, uri, params, headers, redir, timeout)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/RequestsLibrary/RequestsKeywords.py", line 801, in _get_request
    cookies=self.cookies)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
```

My system configuration:

```
Mac OS X (10.11.3)
Python (2.7.10)
openssl (1.0.2f)
requests (2.9.1)
robotframework (3.0)
robotframework-httplibrary (0.4.2)
robotframework-requests (0.4.4)
robotframework-ride (1.5.2.1)
robotframework-sshlibrary (2.1.2)
pyOpenSSL (0.15.1)
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: When you say "probably because of the new updates", what updates are you talking about? To your server? To robot? To the requests module? To python? To OSX?

Comment: I updated robot framework libraries (all of them) mentioned in system config in question. Thanks

Comment: ***`SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)`*** is not telling us much. It looks like it not an accurate error number (to me). Can you provide the error returned from OpenSSL's ***[`ERR_get_error`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/ERR_get_error.html)*** or ***[`SSL_get_error`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_get_error.html)***?

Comment: @jww how do i get that error? I am running robot framework automation scripts and it only shows the traceback error mentioned in the question.

Comment: `${headers}=  Create Dictionary Content-Type application/json  Accept application/json` is wrong, should be `&{headers}= Create Dictionary Content-Type=application/json  Accept=application/json`

Comment: `url` argument of `Get Request` must be relative like `/path`.

Comment: Yes url argument is indeed a relative path. The same script works in my colleague's system. So i think its a config issue, but dont know how to figure that out as OpenSSL doesn't provide enough information on the error. Thanks

Comment: did you notice my previous comment? `Create Dictionary` is wrong. Check [here](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/blob/master/tests/testcase.txt). FYI, use `@user` in the comment to let the user know you've commented back.

Comment: @NizamMohamed i did notice your previous comment. Can you explain why `Create Dictionary` is wrong? Also i did mention that the same script works in other machine, so how can it be wrong? Robot framework has many formats and one of them is `.tsv` which is a keyword driven framework and so there is no need to add `=` in between keywords on right hand side. Thanks

Comment: I didn't know much about robotframework. I just went thorugh the [file](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/blob/master/tests/testcase.txt). In every `Create Dictionary`occurrence in the file, dictionary name is like `&{name}`, not like `${name}` and arguments are space separated.

Comment: @NizamMohamed yeah there are many formats in robot framework. So they vary with each other. However, i am not sure what configuration issue is creating this issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You're all up to date, so there are two possibilities:

- The handshake isn't going smoothly because of a break in the trust chain. Start from the bottom and work up. Are you testing this on a local area network? Is the certificate up to date? Can you access the site from your location and others without an error? [SSL labs](https://dev.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) showing anything up? What about firewall rules?
- There's [a bug](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues) in the recent update. OpenSSL reports in my experience are caused by connection issues rather than obscure software problems - this is the less likely of the two.

Comment: handshake is working as it should be because my colleagues can perform the same operation and it works for them. So i probably guess its because of some configuration issue that's creating this problem.

Comment: Do check your firewall rules if it's specific to yourself! This has caught me out before :(

Comment: I did check my firewall rules and it seems to be fine. I also made sure that python had the rights in firewall by enabling it in recovery mode in mac. Thanks.

Comment: Well this is just headache inducing! It's almost certainly a connection issue - test the library with a hello world is all I can suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing requests[security] instead of requests. It uses PyOpenSSL, which is better than OpenSSL: *[pip install requests[security] vs pip install requests: Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811949/pip-install-requestssecurity-vs-pip-install-requests-difference/31812342#31812342)*

Comment: I ran `pip install -U requests[security]` command, and i got requirement satisfied result in command line. So i think its already installed with requests itself, though i am not sure. But i did install `PyOpenSSL`, `ndg-httpsclient` and `pyasn1` and script still fails. Thanks

Comment: @fodma1 "On Python 3.4+ and Python 2.7.9+ it's not better anymore", see [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/2195#issuecomment-53934322)