# Python web Automation to get Email from Webpage

Tags: python

I want a python script that opens a link and print the email address from that page.

E.g

1. Go to some site like example.com
2. Search for email in that.
3. Search in all the pages in that link.

I was tried below code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.digitalseo.in/')
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for rate in soup.find_all('@'):
    print rate.text
```

> I take this website for reference.

Anyone help me to get this?

Comment: Have you tried that? You can use [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to do that.

Comment: Yes. I tried with BeautifulSoup. But i cant get.

Comment: what is your code? what is the error message? what is the output?

Comment: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.digitalseo.in/')
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for rate in soup.find_all('@'):
    print rate.text

I did't get any output. I take that website just for reference.

Comment: Okay, because `find_all()` function will search the **Tags**, not email address. I'll post an answer to explain this. And I think you should edit your question and add your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `find_all()` will only search **Tags**. From document:

> Signature: `find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit, **kwargs)`
>
> The `find_all()` method looks through a tag’s descendants and retrieves all descendants that match your filters.

So you need add a keyword argument like this:

---

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.digitalseo.in/')
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all(href=re.compile("mailto")):
    print i.string
```

**Demo:**

```
contact@digitalseo.in
contact@digitalseo.in
```

---

From document:

> Any argument that’s not recognized will be turned into a filter on one of a tag’s attributes. If you pass in a value for an argument called id, Beautiful Soup will filter against each tag's 'id' attribute:

```
soup.find_all(id='link2')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>]
```

> If you pass in a value for `href`, Beautiful Soup will filter against each tag's 'href' attribute:

```
soup.find_all(href=re.compile("elsie"))
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>]
```

You can see the document for more info: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

---

And if you'd like find the email address from a document, `regex` is a good choice.

For example:

```
import re
re.findall( '[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+ ', text) # remember change `text` variable
```

---

And if you'd like find a link in a page by keyword, just use `.get` like this:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_link_by_keyword(keyword):
    links = set()
    for i in soup.find_all(href=re.compile(r"[http|/].*"+str(keyword))):
        links.add(i.get('href'))

    for i in links:
        if i[0] == 'h':
            yield i
        elif i[0] == '/':
            yield link+i
        else:
            pass

global link
link = raw_input('Please enter a link: ')
if link[-1] == '/':
    link = link[:-1]

r = requests.get(link, verify=True)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for i in get_link_by_keyword(raw_input('Enter a keyword: ')):
    print i
```

Comment: It's working. Is is possible to find the mail based on the @ symbol.

Comment: No, this will search `href=mailto`. If you check the HTML then you will see some thing like `<a href="mailto:contact@digitalseo.in">`.

Comment: Is there is any way to find E-mail based on the @ symbol. Because in some situations  will be listed without <a href

Comment: Yes, , if you'd like search the email address in a document or some string, use regex instead BeautifulSoup. Let me edit my answer and add it.

Comment: Okay sir. Thank you. It was so helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using regex can we find mail address from webpage.?

Comment: Yes, you can try it :)

Comment: Everything works fine..! Thank you. How do parse only contact us URL in a specific web page..?

Comment: Parse URL in a specific web page? What is the web page looks like?

Comment: Consider my scenario,  I have this website http://www.digitalseo.in/. In that many links are available. But i need only Contact-us page link.?

Comment: So that is you only want a part of links, and search by some keyword?

Comment: Yes. I need only contact and about page links.

Comment: OK, maybe I just need change the keyword...wait me a minute.

Comment: See what did I add, now you can just use a *keyword* then get the link :)

Comment: Sorry for trouble again. If i use www.davimac.com.au instead of http://www.digitalseo.in/ i did't get any output. I know the links was not started with http. But i don't know how to fix this type issues.

Comment: No problem, let me check this link.

Comment: Well, seems like I can't connect to that web site(I know why, but I can't fix it). What are the links looks like? like ``/foo/bar``?

Comment: When extracting the link alone from that site, those links looks like this

/Products/davimac-small-seeds-drive-wheel
/davimac-dealers
/contact
/blog
/field-days

Comment: Okay sir. Thank you..!

Comment: Finished, now this program will ask for a link and a keyword. Try it.

Comment: Sir I got SSL error when processing the https urls. Is there is any way fix this.?

Comment: Sure, That's easy to fix this. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: I've just add `verify=False` in `r = requests.get(link, verify=False)`. What about now?

Comment: No sir. Still i got the same error.   It gives some SSL related errors, then in the last line the error looks llike urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.

Comment: Hmm...`403: Forbidden` means that you haven't permission to connect to that web site. Did you tried use the web browser to connect that web site?

Comment: THIS IS THE ERROR :  /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.6.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning

Comment: I've just google about it. Please try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099404/ssl-insecureplatform-error-when-using-requests-package).

Comment: I installed that package. But still same problem.

Comment: Try reboot the system?

Comment: Yes. I check it after rebooting the system. Still getting same error.

Comment: Well, which OS are you on?

Comment: I am using CentOs 6. With the python version 2.6.5. Is it possible to speak with you personally?,

Comment: personally? Do you mean use phone?

Comment: Yeah. Using Skype or using social media sites.

Comment: I don't have the account of Skype and I didn't install it, What about Google plus?

Comment: And I think CentOS wouldn't get error, what is the web site?

Comment: All the website (https )with ssl giving error.  I already invited you in Google+

Comment: I didn't see that, let me check :)

Comment: I'm sorry about I'm just search and test the code, seems like it will raise an error but will also work.