# pandas installation on ubuntu error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-FM0q5o/pandas/

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, pandas

i tried to install pandas in ubuntu but there is problem.
i already install numpy and go for pandas

> kcn@vaio :~$ sudo pip install pandas

```
The directory '/home/kcn/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/kcn/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pandas
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see "https//urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest"/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading pandas-0.18.1.tar.gz (7.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 7.3MB 97kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil->pandas)
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Running setup.py install for pandas.../   #it took 20 min then.. 
 error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-qXBFie/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-icD0t5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qXBFie/pandas/
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099404/ssl-insecureplatform-error-when-using-requests-package

Comment: Did you already run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: @AnthonyE i shows **requests 2.2.1 does not provide the extra 'security'**

Comment: yeah @BurhanKhalid i do but the still same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this answer by my self
Actually in Ubuntu there are two version of Python already installed
so when pip install we have to do like this
first confirm your which python you are using by this
**python -version**
then make sure  your desire python version by like this:
**alias python=python3** for 3 or **alias python=python2** for 2
and
it means you have got 2 pip version  i.e pip for python version2 pip3 for python version3.
if you wanted to install pandas for python 2.7 you just need to
**sudo pip install pandas**
if you wantes to install pandas for python 3 you just need to
**sudo pip3 install pandas**
after installing pandas if you want to compile your program in 2.7 you do the same
 **alias python=python2**or vice versa
to check ther version in terminal write **>>python**
https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/make-default-python-command-to-use-python-3
this answer provide more information about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Better not mess up with the system python. Use `pip install pandas --user` instead. Or use a virtualenv.

Comment: **pip install pandas --user** having same problem.... but i get install virtualenv and i am confusing with the next step?? –

Answer (score 0):

May be give this a try. It happens when you don't have the Python dev tools installed so the package fails to compile whether you are on v2.7 or 3.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```