# Jython pip installs fail, SNIMissingWarning

Tags: pip, jython-2.7

Recently downloaded Jython and am trying to use it as the interpreter for  virtualenv. However, trying to install anything via pip throws the error messages:

> (jve) ➜  project$ pip install jupyter
>
> Collecting jupyter
>     Using cached jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>
> Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
>   /home/me/python-virtualenvs/notes2nlp2upcodeHCCs-ctakes_proto_jython/Lib/site-packages/pip/*vendor/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:331: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>
> warnings.warn(
>   /home/reedv/python-virtualenvs/notes2nlp2upcodeHCCs-ctakes_proto_jython/Lib/site-packages/pip/*vendor/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:130: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>
> warnings.warn(
>     Using cached jupyter_console-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
>
> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/me/python-virtualenvs/notes2nlp2upcodeHCCs-ctakes_proto_jython/Lib/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "/home/me/python-virtualenvs/notes2nlp2upcodeHCCs-ctakes_proto_jython/Lib/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
>   .
>   .
>   .
>     File "/home/me/python-virtualenvs/notes2nlp2upcodeHCCs-ctakes_proto_jython/Lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/selectors.py", line 50, in _fileobj_to_fd
>       raise ValueError("Invalid file object: {0!r}".format(fileobj))
>   ValueError: Invalid file object:

The message recommends that I " upgrade to a newer version of Python", but I am already using the most up to date version of Jython:

```
(jve) ➜  project$ python --version
Jython 2.7.0
```

Is there anything else that can be done here?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?  I had found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099404/ssl-insecureplatform-error-when-using-requests-package) however I'm not quite sure how to fix, since `pip` won't work...

Comment: @Jim Still have not found a fix and that post you linked to did not help me as well (though I did find that libffi-dev was not installed on my system (ubuntu 16.04), maybe that would help you?)).