# pip not installing any package with warnings " InsecurePlatformWarning, SNIMissingWarning"

Tags: python, pip, pyopenssl, urllib3

Python version: 2.7.6
Pip version: 9.0.3

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install pyOpenSSL
Collecting pyOpenSSL
```

### below is the error while installing any package

> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:339: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, b
>   ut the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to pr
>   esent an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to
>    solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>     SNIMissingWarning
>
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is
>    not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail.
>   You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/
>   latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>     InsecurePlatformWarning
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certify (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for pyOpenSSL

Tried installing `urllib3[secure] --upgrade`, but getting the below error along with InsecurePlatformWarning

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyOpenSSL>=0.14; python_version <= "2.7" and extra == "secure"
>    (from urllib3[secure]) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for pyOpenSSL>=0.14; python_version <= "2.7" and extra == "secure" (from urllib3[secure])

Tried installing the packages suggested in [SSL InsecurePlatform error when using Requests package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099404/ssl-insecureplatform-error-when-using-requests-package?noredirect=1&lq=1) getting the same warning issues.

I cannot upgrade the python version due to some constraints. Any other way to resolve the issue?

Comment: This is marked as duplicate; but the linked answer does not address this question in two different ways:
a) this user is asking for a solution on Windows, the linked answer is for *NIX users
b) this user *cannot* upgrade to the latest version of Python.  This is due to constraints beyond their control, ie. the VFX industry has been slow to update the interpreters their applications rely on.

Answer (score 1):

From python status page:

> The rolling brownouts have been upgraded to a blackout, TLSv1.0 and >TLSv1.1 will be rejected with a HTTP 403 at all times.
>
> Posted about 17 hours ago. Apr 08, 2018 - 15:49 UTC

So you need to check what is your TLS version
you can do it by running the code:

```
import json
import urllib2
print json.load(urllib2.urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check'))['tls_version']
```

If it is less than 1.2 you probably need to upgrade your python version.

Comment: tls version is 1.2, Is there any way to fix without upgrading python version?

Comment: If the tls version is 1.2 so you are good, probably it is another issue

Comment: But probably upgrading to 2.7.9 or more is the best solution.

Comment: Yeah, but I cannot upgrade the python version due to few limitations.