# pip install requests[security] itself throws InsecurePlatform warning/error

Tags: python, https, pip

When running `pip` to install packages over `https` the message

> InsecurePlatformWarning

is a self-described "warning", which is actually an *error*. It causes `pip` installations to fail. The fix is to install the security feature with

```
pip install requests[security]
```

or

```
pip install pyOpenSSL ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```

[according](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent) to [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099404/ssl-insecureplatform-error-when-using-requests-package) different StackOverflow and other threads.

I'm pretty sure this solution worked for me in the past on several machines. However, the solution throws the same error on one of my machines:

> ```
> E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py
> :122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This p
> revents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL con
> nections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. Fo
> r more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#i
> nsecureplatformwarning.
>   InsecurePlatformWarning
> ```

As far as taking the advice in the message to upgrade Python, I can't for this particular machine and use case.

Comment: Can you upgrade `pip` and `pip install pyopenssl>=0.14 cryptography>=1.3.4 idna>=2.0.0`?

Comment: @hoefling Thanks, just gave it a try - same warning/error