# Pycharm failed installing packages because of SSL

Tags: python, ssl, pycharm

I am using Windows 7 virtual machine and I can't add ctypes.
My physical machine runs Ubuntu and the internet connection is a WiFi-hotspot.

Error occured:

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/ctypes/: There was a
>   problem confirming the ssl certificate:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /simple/ctypes/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499:
>   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version'),)) - skipping

Command output:

> Collecting ctypes   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.org/simple/ctypes/: There was a problem confirming the
>   ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /simple/ctypes/ (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) -
>   skipping Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a
>   problem confirming the ssl certificate:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499:
>   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version'),)) - skipping

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:339: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  SNIMissingWarning
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/ctypes/
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/ctypes/
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/ctypes/
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/ctypes/
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/ctypes/
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ctypes (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ctypes
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Comment: this is likely a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099404/ssl-insecureplatform-error-when-using-requests-package

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your urllib security packages e.g. via pip.

```
pip install urllib3[secure]
```

This should guide you:
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl-py2

Your urllib seems to try to access pypi with tlsv1.
Very likely that they don't allow you to, anymore.

Get your toolchain up to date and you should be fine.

**update:**

How to do stuff with pip on windows in different versions is already answered here: [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: I updated the answer. Windows 7 should not be a problem.