# ERROR: The ssl package installed with your Python package workaround for snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-connector

I am using the python connector to read data from snowflake and the python version I have installed on the servers is python `2.7.6`. When trying to connect to snowflake I run into the following:

> ERROR: The ssl package installed with your Python - version 2.7.6 -
> does not have the security fix. Upgrade to Python 2.7.9/3.5.0 or
> higher.

Unfortunately, I can not upgrade python as it will break other stuff and was wondering if there is a way around this error as I've see posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099404/ssl-insecureplatform-error-when-using-requests-package) on disabling warnings for requests package. I know that those are warnings and not the same as errors but trying to avoid the python upgrade if possible.

Comment: As it says you Python version is too old. Upgrade your legacy code to newer Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

`SSLError`
You can try to put pypi.org in your trusted-host!

```py
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org YOU-WANT-TO-INSTALL
```